# Label and reference a symbol that represents a statement?

Tags: cross-referencing

For example, suppose `A \iff B \iff C`. What's a way to put a number (like equation number) on each `\iff` symbol, label them, and reference them separately later?

Comment: Welcome! Why don't you use an `equation` environment?

Comment: If I put `A \iff B \iff C` in an `equation` environment, the reference would refer to the whole thing. I want to specifically refer to `A \iff B` or `B \iff C`. For example, each `\iff` has its own proof. So when proving, I need to specify which `\iff` I'm proving.

Comment: I hope you don't mind but I've edited your question to clarify that. You might look at `tikzmark`, especially if you might need to do this for arbitrary connectives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** after some poking around it now works with old `\ref` and is compatible with `hyperref` (avoid using within a labeled `equation` because `\refstepcounter` messed up the label counter)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{iffcount}
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{
    \newcommand{\liff}[1]{
        \refstepcounter{iffcount}
        \def\Hy@AnchorName{iff.\theiffcount}
        \underset{(\theiffcount)}{\iff}
        \newcounter{#1}
        \setcounter{#1}{\theiffcount}
        \@bsphack    
        \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
            \string\newlabel{#1}{{\theiffcount}{\thepage}{}{\Hy@AnchorName}{}}%
        }%
        \@esphack
        \hyper@@anchor{\Hy@AnchorName}{\relax}%
    }
}{
    \newcommand{\liff}[1]{
        \refstepcounter{iffcount}
        \underset{(\theiffcount)}{\iff}
        \newcounter{#1}
        \setcounter{#1}{\theiffcount}
        \@bsphack
        \protected@write\@auxout{}%
            {\string\newlabel{#1}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}}}%
        \@esphack
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
I claim that \[A\liff{iff:1} B\liff{iff:2} C.\]

I am going to prove \ref{iff:1} here, and prove \ref{iff:2} there.

I also claim that \[C\liff{iff:3} D\liff{iff:4} E.\]

I am going to prove \ref{iff:3} here, and prove \ref{iff:4} there.
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

---

**Old version:**
Here is a rough way of doing it... (does not support `hyperref`!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcounter{iffcount}
\setcounter{iffcount}{1}
\newcommand{\liff}[1]{
    \underset{(\theiffcount)}{\iff}
    \newcounter{#1}
    \setcounter{#1}{\theiffcount}
    \stepcounter{iffcount}
}
\newcommand{\riff}[1]{\arabic{#1}}

\begin{document}
I claim that \[A\liff{iff:1} B\liff{iff:2} C.\]

I am going to prove \riff{iff:1} here, and prove \riff{iff:2} there.

I also claim that \[C\liff{iff:3} D\liff{iff:4} E.\]

I am going to prove \riff{iff:3} here, and prove \riff{iff:4} there.
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I change `underset` to `overset`, replace the newly defined counter `iffcount` with `equation`, put `\displaystyle` before `(\theequation)` in the `overset` to make the numbers bigger, and give the command one more argument so I can use it with any symbol instead of just `\iff`.